# Understanding the working of Unary Operators

Tags: c

What will be the output of the following code? Online compilers give the result: 12 6 11. Can someone tell me how?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)

main()
{
    int i = 10, j = 5, k = 0;
    k = MAX(i++, ++j);
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
}
```

Comment: Well he is trying to understand C. Not sure why the hate.

Comment: Wrong duplicate, @KerrekSB (though it most likely is a duplicate). No UB in here.

Comment: @Kay: You're right, the evaluation is sequenced -- I'm sorry!

Comment: Actually I don't think there's any undefined behavior in this code, the duplicate seems all wrong ...  Perhaps writing your code like this: `k = (i++) > (++j) ? (i++) : (++j)` and get rid of the macro would make it clearer ...

Comment: @dragosht: Yes, my fault - there's no UB, since the evaluations are sequenced.

Comment: @Kay: (Yes, I saw an identical question yesterday or two days ago...)

Comment: @user3894721, do you mean ternary operators in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets translated to:

```
k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j)
```

Now it's easy to tell why..

`i++` makes `i` 11, `++j` makes `j` 6. Now we have:

```
10 > 6
```

Which is true, then we return `i++`, which is 12 now.

Use the `-E` flag to see the output of the pre-processor.

Comment: Maybe you could rewrite this a little bit. `?:` → `if else`, `i++` → `++i; … i`

Answer (score 0):

```
k = MAX(i++, ++j);
```

This code will be replaced by

```
k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
```

when checking the condition `(i++)>(++j)`, `i` is post increment(after the operation it will increment) and `j` is pre-increment( increment the `j` and substitute it). so while checking it will take (10) > (6), it is true! after this check `i` will become 11.

```
k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j); --> k = (i++)>(++j)?((11)++):(++j); // note after condition check i becomes 11.
// due to post increment after assigning the value to k, i will be incremented to 12. but the last ++j wont excuted.
```

So you will get output `12 6 11`.

else you can rewrite the `k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);` as

```
if((i++)>(++j)) //when condition check i=10, j=6 after check i=11,j=6
k=i++; // k= 11++; after assigning 11 to k i will be incremented to 12
else
k=++j; // this wont be executed
```